# Aligning All Equations in a Document at Equality Sign

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

This question may seem a little insane! :) but I am inclined to align **all** of my equations in a document at the `=` sign. In fact, I want a general format for all of the equations like below

> The distance of equality sign from the left margin which I want to be fixed = right side

and if the left side or right side of the equation are long they should break down to next line aligning from the left.

Here is simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

This example shows text and  equations within
an \verb|align| environment.
\begin{align*}
a &= b + c + d\\
  &+ e + f + g
\intertext{A small amount of text can go here with $x=2$ inline math
But not a lot of text.}
k &= l + m + n + m + n + m + n\\
  &+ o + p + q
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

But not exactly what I want since

- the distance of `=` is not fixed form the left margin
- if I use this method I should write all of my document in one `align` environment which will be too confusing!
- I cannot write too much text between equations

Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: What are you currently using to align or write your equations?

Comment: @Werner: I usually use align environment for aligning equations

Comment: @Werner: Do you think that there may be a solution? :)

Comment: What if you have `\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1` somewhere? I mean, what's the reason for aligning completely unrelated equations at the same point?

Comment: @egreg: I think that the only reason I can refer to is beauty! :) In some documents I prefer it to be this way. Or maybe the reason is my *aligmentoholic* disease! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only considered implementing a global alignment as egreg hinted in comments that it was a bad idea. Alignment is supposed to highlight the corresponding parts of a display and that meaning is destroyed if you align everything. But...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength\mathindent{3cm}
\makeatletter

\def\align@preamble{%
   &\hfil
    \strut@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \llap{\set@field}%
    \tabskip\z@skip
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \rlap{\set@field}
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@
}


\def\a{One two three four five six seven. }
\def\b{\a\a\a Red yellow blue green. \a\a\a\a}
\begin{document}

\b\b\a
\begin{align}
  1+2+3+4 &=4\\
x+y &=z
\end{align}

\b\b\b

\a\a\b

\a
\begin{align}
  1&=a+y+b+w+x+n+m+s+d+e\\
  2&=4
\end{align}

\b
\begin{align}
  1&=0\\
2&=9
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

the macros here are not particularly general or robust but show a basic idea of using a flush left but very indented setting along with hiding the width of the first column.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. Yeah it may look bad for some purposes and look nice for another things! I mentioned at the beginning of my question that it may look insane! :D

Answer (score 6):

Equations can be left aligned by option `fleqn`. The left indentation can be controlled by register `\mathindent` (package `amsmath`). Then the left part of the equation can be written via `\llap` in the indentation space:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{3em}
\newcommand*{\ml}[1]{%
  \llap{$\displaystyle#1$}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \ml{a} = b + c + d\\
  {} + e + f + g
\intertext{A small amount of text can go htere with $x=2$ inline math,
but not a lot of text.}
  \ml{k} = l + m + n + m + n + m + n\\
  {} + o + p + q\\
  \ml{r + s} = t + u
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]