# How to have better tab and alignment in maths equations?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, lists

Instead of typing the `\hspace{30mm}` or otherwise to set the space, are there any other ways to efficiently 'tabbing' different equations in different alignment environments?

Sorry if the code is bad, got it from somewhere else, and I may need the same template for future equations in my document.

```
\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{45pt}
\begin{enumerate}
[align=left,widest=a,labelindent=16mm,leftmargin=!]
    \item%1
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sin{\theta}=\frac{\text{O}}{\text{H}} \hspace{30pt}%%%%
        \cos{\theta}=\frac{\text{A}}{\text{H}} \hspace{30pt}%%%%
        \tan{\theta}=\frac{\text{O}}{\text{A}}
        \end{aligned}
        $
    \item%3
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sec{\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}} \hspace{16pt}%%%%HERE%%%%
        \csc{\theta}=\frac{1}{\sin{\theta}} \hspace{17pt}%%%%HERE%%%%
        \cot{\theta}=\frac{1}{\tan{\theta}}
        \end{aligned}
        $
\end{enumerate}
```

See in item 3, I have to physically adjust the length to align the equations, as in the picture below: (Ignore 4 and so on)

[image]

I have used the *align* environment before, but how do I make sure the alignment is always constant, unlike the image below: ***(my aim is to control the imaginary red lines to align every equations and texts)***

[image]

And, can I manually control the tabbing throughout the whole document and/or at every section?
(Oh I realised I forgot to add the $h$ but it is alright)

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your equations. For what you like to have, maybe writing equation in equal formatted tables (arrays) is a way to go.

Comment: I think I saw a Lua-based package that makes it easier to keep such vertical alignments from a math environment to the next, but I can't find it right now... Another possibility: would you be OK with a tabular instead of an enumerate?

Comment: Also, the LaTeX code you posted doesn't match the image... Please make sure that you post a Minimal Working Example (=compilable) so that it's easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: [align - Aligning All Equations in a Document at Equality Sign - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343911/aligning-all-equations-in-a-document-at-equality-sign)